# Grab Account info to send email RE: Task

Tags: trigger, account

I wrote a trigger to send an email to a Salesman and Trader on an Account when a task is logged for that Account.

However, I'm running into the issue that sometimes these calls are logged at the Contact level, but the Salesman and Trader should still receive emails.

Do I need to write another trigger to handle this?  Or can it be incorporated into the original?

Thanks in advance.

Current Trigger:

```
trigger updateEmails on Task (before insert) {

      Set<Id> acctIds = new Set<Id>();
      for(Task t : trigger.new){
        String wId = t.WhatId;
        if(wId!=null && wId.startsWith('001') && !acctIds.contains(t.WhatId)){
           acctIds.add(t.WhatId);
        }
      }

      List<Account> taskAcct = [Select Id, Trader__r.Email, Salesman__r.Email from Account where Id in :acctIds];
      Map<Id, Account> acctMap = new Map<Id, Account>();
      for(Account a : taskAcct){
         acctMap.put(a.Id,a);
      }

      for(Task t : trigger.new){
          String wId = t.WhatId;
          if(wId!=null && wId.startswith('001')){
             Account thisAcct = acctMap.get(t.WhatId);
             if(thisAcct!=null){
               t.Trader_Email__c = thisAcct.Trader__r.Email;
               t.Salesman_Email__c = thisAcct.Salesman__r.Email;
      }
   }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can update the same trigger to include Coantct tasks as well. This will do it

```
trigger updateEmails on Task (before insert) {

    Set<Id> acctIds = new Set<Id>();
    Set<ID> conIDs = new Set<Id>();
    for(Task t : trigger.new){
        String wId = t.WhatId;
        //I am continuing with hardcoded 001 and 003 as they remain constant
        //https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewSolution?id=000005995&language=en_US

        if(!String.isBlank(wId)) {
            if(wId.startsWith('001') && !acctIds.contains(t.WhatId)){
                acctIds.add(t.WhatId);
            }
            else if(wId.startsWith('003') && !conIDs.contains(t.WhatId)){
                conIDs.add(t.WhatId);
            }
        }

    }
    //Change the map to Contact id and Account ID    
    Map<Id, ID> conMap = new Map<Id, ID>();
    for(Contact con : [Select accountId From Contact Where ID in :conIDS limit :conIDS]){
        acctIds.add(con.accountId);    
        conMap.put(con.id,con.accountId);
    }

    Map<Id, Account> acctMap = new Map<Id, Account>([Select Id, Trader__r.Email, Salesman__r.Email from Account where Id in :acctIds]);

    Account thisAcct;
    for(Task t : trigger.new){
        String wId = t.WhatId;
        if(!String.isBlank(wId)){
            if(wId.startswith('001')){
                thisAcct = acctMap.get(wId);    
            }
            else if(wId.startswith('003'))
                thisAcct = acctMap.get(conMap.get(wId));
        }
        if(thisAcct!=null){
            t.Trader_Email__c = thisAcct.Trader__r.Email;
            t.Salesman_Email__c = thisAcct.Salesman__r.Email;
        }
    }
}
```

> I am assuming each of your contact has a Parent account.

Comment: The only issue seems to be when we're pushing the Account Id into the Map.  When running conMap.put(con.id,con.AccountId); it's giving me this error:  Incompatible value type Id for Map

Comment: I was copy pasting your existing code and made this mistake. Map type should be of Map<ID,ID>. I have updated the code.

Comment: Mark the answer as Best answer to help others. Cheers.